# What do you call the entire mechanical system that makes a bicycle rotate?

Tags: word-request

What do you call the entire mechanical system that makes a bicycle rotate?

[image]

This is a bicycle and in the bottom left you have the mechanical system that makes the back wheel rotate. I am not just talking about the pedal, but the whole mechanical system, of which the pedal is just a part. Is there a name for the system (drive chain, pedal, etc.)?

Comment: Does a word exist for this in your native language? Have you use a bilingual dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The analogous thing for a car would be called a *drivetrain:*

> the system in a motor vehicle which connects the transmission to the drive axles.

It seems from some googling that this word is also used for bicycles, for example see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bicycle_drivetrain_systems